# Checking out points from File Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase, arcpad

I'm using ArcMap 10.1 with ArcPad 10.0.  I am trying to learn how to use the check-out and check-in functionality with a file geodatabase.

The database I'm has 13 feature classes in it, most of which are empty because I'm just starting with this project.  The ones that have data are things like the project area, the survey grid, and a transect line.

When I use the 'Get Data for ArcPad' tool on the ArcPad Data Manager toolbar and try to set the action for all the layers I choose 'Checkout all Geodatabase layers and copyout all other layers'.  The problem is that only the line and polygon layers are listed as being checked out:

[image]

All the other layers, which are points, are listed as being exported as background data as shapefiles.  All of these feature classes are in the same database, with the same projection.

What is going on with this tool that I can't checkout the other layers?

The option to checkout the point layers isn't even available under action.

Here are the options for the Project Area (polygon) layer:

[image]

And here are the options for the Misc_Point layer (point), note that the option for 'Check Out for disconnected editing in ArcPad' is totally missing here:

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use the [ArcPad Check Out GeoProcessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/index.html#/ArcPad_Check_Out/00s1000000mz000000/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check out data you need to ensure that the XY tolerance on the layers is the same. Otherwise ArcPad will choose the first layers it encounters for XY tolerance are correct and other layers with other tolerances will be background data.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if feature classes have different coordinate systems to the map document, they can't be checked out.